# how to decode Redis ft search query?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

So I am new to redis and I am trying to learn everything I possible can and later want to add this for caching in my website.
But, I am currently encountering a very small problem, I have no idea of any function how to decode the return query from the ft function.

The code is below:

```
import redis
import json
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
from redis.commands.search.query import Query,NumericFilter
r=redis.Redis(host="192.168.196.75",port=6379)
user1 = {
        "name": "Paul John",
        "email": "paul.john@example.com",
        "age": 42,
        "city": "London",
        "id":1,
        "username":"Paul Walker",
}

# r.json().set("user:1",Path.root_path(),user1)

loc=r.ft("Idx").search(query="@username:Paul")
print(loc)
```

The output I am getting is `Result{1 total, docs: [Document {'id': 'user:1', 'payload': None, 'json': '{"name":"Paul John","email":"paul.john@example.com","age":42,"city":"London","id":1,"username":"Paul Walker"}'}]}`

As you can see everything is working fine, But I am not able to derive the dictioniary that has the information, I can try to make many steps like splitting and slicing but I think there is a function for this which I am not able to find.
It would be very helpful If anyone knows what that is. Thank you for reading my question

Answer (score 1):

for retrieving just the documents you can use the `.docs` such as:

`loc=r.ft("Idx").search(query="@username:Paul").docs` retrieving all results or `.docs[0]` for the first element and on

Comment: Thanks for answering my questoin you are right, For selecting .docs[0] is used and then to get the JSON value we just put .json in front of it, So the whole string will be loc=r.ft("Idx").search(query="@username:Paul").docs[0].json , after this it can easily be loaded in json module